# Error pages in .htaccess - find the requested page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use my .htaccess file to redirect visitors with errors to my custom error pages.
The server is an Apache with PHP 5.2 so I code in PHP.
I wish to know, on my PHP error pages, what page did the visitor request and gave an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

or

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']
```

should give you the information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it via ErrorDocument, you should find the original URL in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and in `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`.

In order to test it, I would advise to make a script, say info.php, which has:

```
 <?php
 phpinfo();
```

and then do something like:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /somepath/info.php
```

And then when you call to non-existing document, you'll receive `phpinfo()` output that lists all variables you have and you can see which ones fit your purposes.

Of course, do not do it on publicly accessible server since `phpinfo()` has a lot of sensitive information.

Comment: Dr.Molle answered faster, sorry. BTW I used the echo function to view the URI.